# Unable to move file in unix

Tags: linux, file, unix, permissions, permission-denied

I am new to unix.

I am trying to move a file from one file system to another in unix. The id which i use is a group id and not owner id. The file is having rw-rw-r-- access. When i try to move the file from one file system to other it says permission denied.

**Example**
Server : Linux
Source path : /test/input
Destination path : /test/archive
File name : data.txt
Permissions : rw-rw-r--
Owner id : id1
My id : id2
Both id1 and id2 belongs to same group.
When i try to move the file from source to destination it says permission denied.

How to fix this?

Comment: Does the group have write permission on the destination directory and the source directory?

Comment: Try to ask this question in: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry silly error from myside.

Previously i have added the owner id to my group so it did not work.
Now i have added my id to owner group and it worked.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

You may consider change the ownership of the file, or directly copy it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the ownership of the directory where you are trying to move the file.Using

```
chown -R <youruserid> /test/archive
```